# Database functional dependency BCNF help

Tags: normalization

I understand most of BCNF and have been able to complete numerous problems with it, I'm just having trouble applying it to the following situation:

R(A,B,C,D,E) FDs: { A->D; BE->A; CD->E }

Here's what I have so far:

```
Relationship1: (A,D)
Relationship2: (A,B,E)
Relationship3: (B,C,E)
```

However with this setup the CD->E functional dependency isn't considered. Should that be taken into account in a new relationship, or should D (or maybe even A?) be added to Relationship 3?

For what it's worth, I determined that:

```
BCE+ = ABCDE
BE+ = ABDE
AC+ = ACDE
```

I'm just not sure where to go from here. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up "dependency preservation".

It is a known phenomenon that when decomposing relation schemas (along some given FD), certain other FD's can become inexpressible.

In a complete logical design, they have to be reinstated as a constraint on the database.  However, normalization theory does not cover constraints.  Normalization theory deals only with relation schemas, not with constraints between them.

If you first decompose over CD->E (leaving ABCD / CDE), you can still further decompose over A->D (leaving AD / ABC / CDE), but you will now have "lost" the BE->A dependency.

Comment: That was the other thing I ended up doing after posting (starting from CD->E). So you're saying my original answer would be correct? Would I be just as correct saying `R1(A,D), R2(A,B,E), R3(B,C,E)` as I would be saying `R1(C,D,E), R2(A,D), R3(A,B,C)` since neither of them have any FDs that are not keys?

Comment: As far as normal forms theory is concerned, yes.  As far as logical database design is concerned, remember that xNF is not where the story ends.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Erwin. This was just a practice exam for my database exam asking to convert to BCNF, so I don't have to worry about anything past that for this question.